# How can extract top scoring intent from LUIS response?

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I am trying to create a custom scenario in Microsoft Healthcare bot. I have created a LUIS model and has successfully integrated with the LUIS element of scenario editor ie, I can send request to my luis model. Now, I don't know how to extract the top scoring intent from the luis response and give it to a statement element.

Comment: Are you using intent mapping according to this document? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/HealthBot/language_model_howto

Comment: Yes. Anyway i got it...

Comment: Are you saying you've solved your issue? Please post that as an answer